# Issue with Cocorico on Docker and Mongo

Tags: database, mongodb, docker

I'm on Macos Mojave, I'm learning docker and cocorico to use the marketplace.
I've installed cocorico from cocolabs, mongo and mysql with docker, but now the supervisor tell "mysql is exited".
I have some trouble with my db : `http://localhost:9001/?message=Process%20mysql%20started`

[image: SCREEN SUPERVISOR]

[image: SCREEN DB ERROR]

[image: DOCKER ACTIVE CONTAINER]

I need help to create db I think I'm noob in docker and symfony and there's no tutorial video or anything.

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

Could you upload your Dockerfile and docker-compose? I'll try to investigate from that.

Comment: I used from github
https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: I used : " docker build " to run Dockerfile to launch cocorico with the final message "cocorico is alive " and now i have ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on 127.0.0.1